# what is the second approach?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

***Question*** :

There are 9 vans , 5 are long wheel and 4 short.

If you want 4 vans where at least 2 vans should be long wheels , how many combination can you have?

**My Approach**

explanation:

1. Combinations with 2 long & 2 short vans:

Choose 2 long vans from 5: 5C2 = 10 ways
Choose 2 short vans from 4: 4C2 = 6 ways
Total combinations for this case: 10 * 6 = 60

2. Combinations with 3 long & 1 short van:

Choose 3 long vans from 5: 5C3 = 10 ways
Choose 1 short van from 4: 4C1 = 4 ways
Total combinations for this case: 10 * 4 = 40

3. All 4 vans are long:

Choose 4 long vans from 5: 5C4 = 5 ways

4. Total combinations:

Add the combinations from all cases:

Total combinations = Case 1 + Case 2 + Case 3 = 60 + 40 + 5 = 105

***My Concern***

Can we do it with another approach where you calculate the total combinations first and then subtract the unwanted combinations?

Answer (score 4):

Sure. There are $9C4=126$ combinations. The unwanted have either $0$ or $1$ long wheel vans. There are $4C4=1$ ways to choose four short wheel (and zero long), and $4C3\cdot 5C1=20$ ways to choose three short wheel and one long. So there are $1+20=21$ bad combinations and $126-1-20=105$ good combinations.